# Does the vitoolkit require vmserver 2.0?

Tags: virtualization, powershell

Does the vitoolkit require vmserver 2.0? or can it be used on the 1. versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [release notes for vi toolkit 1.5](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/windowstoolkit/wintk15/windowstoolkit15-200901-releasenotes.html) will tell you which VMware environments is supported:

- VMware ESX 3.5
- VMware ESX 3i
- VMware VirtualCenter 2.5
- VMware ESX 3.0/VirtualCenter 2.0